# Re-open form popup after submission

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a popup contact form using JS and CSS to display/hide. The PHP is working and the form is being submitted. However once the submit button has been clicked the page refreshes and you have to manually reopen the contact from to see any validation errors or the success message.

On refresh I would like the form to be displayed without having to manually reopen it. I have tried to add the following jQuery but nothing is working. Please help!

```html
<?php include('contact_form_process.php'); ?>
<div class="form-popup" id="myForm">
  <form class="form-container" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
    <h1>Send us a message</h1>
    <span><?= $name_error ?></span><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" value="<?= $name ?>" name="name"><br>
    <span><?= $email_error ?></span><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" value="<?= $email ?>" name="email"><br>
    <span><?= $message_error ?></span><br>
    <textarea type="text" placeholder="Enter Message" value="<?= $message ?>" style="height:200px" name="message"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit Message</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()"></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

```js
$('.form-container').submit(function(e) {
  $('#myForm').css('display', 'block');
});

function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "block";
};

function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").style.display = "none";
};

$('.form-container').submit(function() {
  $('#myForm').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: As the page is being refreshed on the form submission the simplest way to do this would be to add some PHP logic to add the `display: block` styling to the `form` HTML, instead of messing with your jQuery. Also note that you have attached the `submit()` event handler twice - the second one can be removed.

Comment: Don't `submit` the form but make an ajax call to POST the form, then handle the response by updating the HTML in the form.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks - yep ajax call to post worked! Knew nothing about ajax prior so it only too 3 days to work out! thanks for the advice....